# duplicate issue when inserint value to varbinary

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, duplicates, varbinary

We face a very weird issue.

we have one table in our mssql 2008 R2 db  when table column is the follow:

1. userId - int
2. userName - varbinary(256)
3. userType - int

**and userName column  is unique**

we preform the following query again the table:

```
insert into table_name (userId, userName, userType) values ( 1 ,  0x5942C803664B00, 0)
```

and after that query we do the following query :

```
insert into table_name (userId, userName, userType) values ( 2 ,  0x5942C803664B, 0)
```

and we get the following Error:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'table_name ' with unique index 'table_name _userName_u'.

although  0x5942C803664B and 0x5942C803664B00 are different values??

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you posted the exact usernames that cause the problem. I cannot replicate this error using your values. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2faf2/1

Comment: @GarethD You're not doing it properly. You're casting a string to a varbinary. If you look at your fiddle result (first select), you can see two `,48,48` which are two bytes with the ordinal value 48 representing the ASCII character "0". Those are not the byte 0x00. Try this instead `INSERT T VALUES (0x5942C803664B00),(0x5942C803664B);`

Comment: Wow. Apparently I need more coffee, and to probably double check everything I have done this morning because that was a pretty basic error... Whoops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trailing "zero-bytes" 0x00 in a varbinary column is as insignificant as the trailing spaces " " in a varchar column.  Therefore, your values are actually duplicates.

In other words, your two values are (in byte order)

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  --- bytes in the binary value
59 42 C8 03 66 4B
59 42 C8 03 66 4B 00
```

The last byte (8 bits of 0) is considered insignificant for the purposes of comparison.  This is the same reason why you get

```
select CASE WHEN 'abc ' = 'abc' then 'SAME' else 'DIFFERENT' end
-- select case when 0x5942C803664B = 0x5942C803664B00 then 'same' else 'different' end

result
======
SAME
```

To make the trailing zero-bytes significant, you can cheat and add something equally to both parts.

```
select case when 0x5942C803664B + 0xff = 0x5942C803664B00 + 0xff
            then 'same'
            else 'different' end   -- different

select case when 0x5942C80366AA + 0xff = 0x5942C80366AA + 0xff
            then 'same'
            else 'different' end   -- same
```

Comment: but 0x5942C803664B and 0x5942C803664B00 are different number... what shout be the column type the will not ignore this? I will understand that 0x5942C803664B and 0x005942C803664B are the same?